# Replace a string X times N amount of times

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a query string and I'm replacing X times N amount of times.

I have a list of object with string name and list of string properties.

```
public class Tag
{
    public string name;
    public List<string> value;
}
```

The string is a simple where clause of an sql statement. Essentially:

```
'Column1' = '[CustomValue1]' AND 'Column2' = '[CustomValue2]'
```

I need to iterate through the values of the tags and replace `CustomValues` with whatever the values of my the tags are. The problem with this implementation is that it isnt dynamic. This code wont work if there is another AND clause e.g. `'Column1' = '[CustomValue1]' AND 'Column2' = '[CustomValue2]' AND 'Column3' = '[CustomValue3]'`

I need to replace the string multiple times because I'm getting data from a table and storing it to my `data` variable.

```
List<Tag> tagList = new List<Tag>();

Tag tag1 = new Tag()
{
    name = "CustomValue1",
    value = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }
};

Tag tag2 = new Tag()
{
    name = "CustomValue2",
    value = new List<string>() { "8", "9", "10" }
};

tagList.Add(tag1);
tagList.Add(tag2);

List<string> customValue = new List<string>() { "CustomValue1", "CustomValue2" };
string str = "Column1' = '[CustomValue1]' and 'Column2' = '[CustomValue2]'";
Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for(int i = 0; i < tagList[0].value.Count; i++)
{
    string tempStr = str;
    tempStr = str.Replace("[" + customValue[0] + "]", tagList[0].value[i]);
    for (int k = 0; k < tagList[1].value.Count; k++)
    {
        var tempStr1 = tempStr.Replace("[" + customValue[1] + "]", tagList[1].value[k]);

        // Merge is a extension method I made that appends the value of the keys from one dictionary to another. 
        // The dictionary will always have the same keys because I am querying in the same table.
        data = data.Merge(QueryStatement(tempStr));
    }
}
```

How can I better optimize this code? What can I do if the string has another AND clause?

Comment: If the number of tags is variable, shouldn't you build the where clause programmatically, rather than pre-building the where clause and replacing parts of it? Also beware of SQL injection, if that's a concern.

Comment: If you want your code reviewed and optimized, perhaps you're better off on [the code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @john I'm sorry. I'm not sure what you mean by building the where clause programmatically. Let me edit the code so it would be clear what I would replacing the string for.

Comment: As in (pseudocode) `for i to tagCount { str = str + (str.length == 0 ? " and " : "") + "column" + i + " = '" + value + "'"; }`

Comment: @john Oh I understand. The where clause is provided by a third party so I cannot build it programmatically.

Comment: Then you're limited to the two columns you already have.

Comment: @JamesWhyte I posted in the code review SE and I was told it did not match what the site was about.

Comment: Perhaps then, Vince, you should re-think your question. Pose one question, the code review, to the review site. And here you should pose the "How would I go about (X)" question. That would be what I would do, as it separates up the two issues nicely.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194086/31562 (where it currently has some close votes from a previous revision of the question, IMO it is better now)